# SAP Webservice error creating production order

Tags: .net, sapb1

I've got an issue with an application we are writting using the SAP business one web service. It was working ok with our test database, but when we have gone onto a test production database we have hit the issue.

When we are adding a production order, we keep getting the following error -

Invalid Code  [OWOR.Series]

It has created the sales order ok, and if you manually create a prouction order with the same lines it works ok. It also works once if you reset the production document numbers, but then it stops working with the same error again.

This worked fine in our test system, so i'm asuming there is something amiss with the numbering, but i have no idea what.

thanks
Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so i worked it out. Turns out the call to the login API is very picky about the database name. It all needs to be in lowercase, no idea why but when I passed it lowercase it worked as expected. Very odd.